# OpenCV. Can't open video from usb camera on the screen

Tags: raspbian, python, opencv

When I'm trying to start simple code, the frame opens and don't respond.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()  
    cv2.imshow('AIR',frame)
```

Camera's index is 0.
Who can suggest anything?

Comment: Can you get output using a video capture application? Cheese for instance